# context parameter is empty on getServerSideProps when page refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, routeparams, nextjs-dynamic-routing

In one of my projects, I need to fill **the meta keyword** and **the meta description** by the data which is fetched from a REST API request.
so I used the `getServerSideProps` function, to fetch the response and pass it to the page.
Here's my getServerSideProps function

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {


    function makeParam() {
        let params = new URLSearchParams(context.params);
        let keysForDel = [];
        params.forEach((v, k) => {
            if (v === 'undefined')
                keysForDel.push(k)
        });
        keysForDel.forEach(k => {
            params.delete(k)
        });
        return params.toString()
    }

    let response = await axios.post(
        process.env.baseAddress + "getData.php",
        qs.stringify({
            data: "api/search/advance?" + makeParam()
        }),
        {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        })

    return {
        props: {
            dataFromServer: response.data,
            params: makeParam()
        },
    }
}
```

everything works fine in development mode (localhost), but after deploying, by refreshing the page **Context parameter** is an empty object.
this function was written in one of the pages that has one parameter called the city, which is shown below
[image: page file]

I have already checked [getServerSideProps props empty object](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11873).
as Ankri said

> Can you please check, that you pass the pageProps to your custom Component?

here is my `Component` tag, which contains pageProps.

```
<Layout>
    <Component {...pageProps} ref={current}/>
</Layout>
```

Comment: How are you verifying that the context parameter is an empty object? Also, can you show us the component where you're using the `params` prop to populate the meta tags?

Answer (score 0):

First make the file structure like this:

```
pages:
  city:
   [...slug].js
```

Note: city is folder!

Now you can get the first param like this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
 const slug = context?.query?.slug[0] || "";
 const req = await axios.post(`${url}?advance=${slug}`)
 // ... rest of the code 
}
```

now if url looks like this => http://localhost:300/city/japan
slug = japan